# iOS: Override UIAppearance appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiappearance

I have a global theme applied that changes the background color of a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.  Below is the code:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGray]];
```

There is an instance on one screen, where I wish to override this color and change the color to white.  I have tried the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderView") as? HeaderView

    headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    return headerView
}
```

However, the headerView still appears with a light gray background.  Any ideas on how to override it?

Comment: Have you tried not dequeueing the HeaderFooterView & just creating a new view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` - say `WhiteUITableViewHeaderFooterView` and configure that for the correct header.

Then, you can set the appearance for views in that class `[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[WhiteUITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor white]];`

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the background color within the `HeaderView` class itself in a method like `LayoutSubviews()`? You can make a `property` of this class representing wether this is the right view for changing its background color. Not sure if this is the best way to achieve this but should be a workaround.